# Intuitive explanation of topological genus?

Tags: surfaces, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I see that the standard definition of genus is:

"A topologically invariant property of a surface defined as the largest number of nonintersecting simple closed curves that can be drawn on the surface without separating it. Roughly speaking, it is the number of holes in a surface. "

Why is it that under this definition, a sphere has a genus of 0, while a torus has a genus of 1?

Answer (score 0):

> "Why is it that under this definition, a sphere has a genus of 0, while a torus has a genus of 1?"

Intuitively speaking, every closed curve in $S^2$ separate it in at least two pieces (think about the equator or a parallel or something like this).

The torus is different. There exist (at least one) closed curve that do not separate it. Think about curves like these:

[image: a torus]

These curves (individually) separate torus on a connected topological space (a cylinder or a circular crown). And both cylinder and circular crown have genus 0 (why?).
Thus, torus has genus 1.

Comment: Thanks - so in your graphic, which curve does not separate the torus, the pink or red curve?

Comment: Both curves. Let $T$ be the torus, $P$ be the pink curve and $R$ be the red one. We have that $T\setminus P$ is a "ring" and $T\setminus R$ is a cylinder (both connected).

Comment: I apologize, when I said 'rectangle' I've made a huge mistake. It should be a kind of ring (a circular crown).

Comment: How is this ring different than a parallel on the globe? Why are the parallels on the globe considered to be rings that "separate" while the rings in the graphic above do not ?

Comment: Let $S^2$ be the sphere and $P$ be a parallel on it. We say that $P$ separates $S^2$ because $S^2\setminus P$ is disconnected (in fact, it has two components homeomorphic to a disk). What can we say about $S^2\setminus C$, where $C$ is any closed curve in $S^2$?.

Comment: However, the curves in the graphic above do not separate the torus because, as I said before, the sets $T\setminus R$ and $T\setminus P$ are still connected.